# javagent requires a jar. How to build and test with that with Gradle?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jvm, gradle, javaagents

I'm building a JavaAgent which can be loaded either via `--javaagent:my.jar=<option>` or dynamically attached to the jvm at runtime (e.g. `virtualMachine.loadAgent(jarFile, "");`). In any case it requires a Jar file with proper manifest.txt file to work. Which is a problem for my tests right now.

I'm using Gradle and I'm currently struggeling with the following problems:

1. Gradle's Test task does not depend on Jar ([see here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)) => need to add
   that dependency for test execution
2. By default the compiled test classes are add to the class path. The test class path must be removed and replaced by the jar file name

Any idea how to achieve that. Especially the 2nd?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't focus on 1, that is trivial: `test.dependsOn jar`. It's the 2nd problem I'm struggling with

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by 'compiled test classes' in 2, you actually mean the main classes

If so, you should be able to do 1 & 2 like this

```
 sourceSets {
     test {
         runtimeClasspath = output + configurations.testRuntime 
     }
 }

dependencies {
   testRuntime files(jar.archivePath) {
        builtBy jar
   }
}
```